# Android Google map API - получить информацию о месте по кликнотому дому накрте

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-places-api

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Я использую для этой задачи API Google Map, но подходящих методов не нашел(возможно, плохо искал). Подскажите, как решить данную задачу.